# Recurring Event or Automatically push Entry date forward in ExpressionEngine

Tags: expressionengine

I've got an events channel set up on a client site where everything is working just fine. However they now have a single event that runs every Sunday. Due to using the start_on parameter to only show events from the current month onwards this recurring event is now displaying a blank page.

Is there a simple way to have the entries publish date automatically updated to the current month or somehow display recurring events correctly. Client is unwilling to spend money on a new module such as Solspace Calendar.

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of. Solspace calendar would be a great investment though. Just quote them how much it would take you to develop from scratch, they will quickly see the value in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a cron job on the server to run a PHP script which would modify the entry date on your recurring entry.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I see your dilemma, Sean - separating the event from its month and year (year in particular) to have one even display multiple times... What about using MX Clone to simply allow them to create multiple instances of the same entry (granted, they'd have to adjust the date for each one too, but that can be done en masse from the mass edit screen if you're using one of the native date fields and not a custom date field)?

Comment: I know it's a little more work for them, but then if there actually ARE any differences between occurrences, because they are unique entries, they can handle that. And MX Cloner is free, so there's that going for it too!

Answer (score 0):

Could you make the entry sticky? Not sure whether that would override the start_on parameter or not.